# Maximize in the direction $\frac{\nabla f}{|| \nabla f||}$

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, differential-forms

Let $ p\in \mathbb{R^n}$ and $S(p,1)$ be the unit sphere, prove that $df\restriction_{S(p,1)}:S(p,1)\mapsto \mathbb{R}$  is maximized in the direction $\frac{\nabla f}{|| \nabla f||}$

---

$df(v)=\nabla f\cdot v =||\nabla f ||||v|||cos(\theta )$, now because $v\in S(p,1)\Rightarrow ||v||=1$
and we get $df(v)=||\nabla f ||cos(\theta ) $ which of course maximized when $cos(\theta)=1$

In order to make $\nabla f$ a unit vector, we divide with its length.

is my solution correct ?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: Unless of course $\nabla f  = 0$, but the problem statement implicitly assumes that's not the case.

Comment: its correct, but its better to use \| instead of || to denote a norm

Comment: The differential-forms and differential-geometry tags are really not appropriate. This is just plain old multivariable calculus/analysis. I disagree that you should take a sphere centered at $p$. This should be about $df_p$ acting on the unit sphere centered at the *origin*. And you should be careful and write $\nabla f(p)$, etc.